# Why do Pokémon characters always act like they love their food?

Tags: pokemon

Why do Pokémon characters always act like they love their food, they can't always like eating food, can they?

Why do Pokémon characters always act like they love their food?

Comment: Are you referring to the creatures, or the people? And is this in shows or in the games?

Comment: I mean.. have you ever had a dog? Or been around a dog and food?

Comment: Depends on the food.  I mean... donuts are great.  Jelly-filled are my favorite.

Comment: Why would you eat food you don’t love?

Comment: @ToddWilcox because you're hungry?

Answer (score 7):

If you're asking about the creatures, i.e. the Pokémon specifically, then that's pretty straightforward. My dog has been fed the same stuff for *years*, and he still eats it like it's his favourite meal on earth, even when I give him all sorts of treats as well. Animals love food, that's a pretty straightforward given.

As for the people; when looking at anime, this is a fairly common trope. Anime always likes to depict a rather exotic cuisine; ramen being the main one, and even that is considered (especially in my experience) to be a fairly delicious meal. Sushi, even rice balls, while simple, still do pack a lot of flavour into their dishes; but again, these are often uncommon treats. The usual evening meal being a simple stir fry of meat, vegetables and rice, sometimes even without the meat.

Pokémon is one of the shows/games where food is never a regular thing - it's not a focus in the series. The main focus is the Pokémon themselves. Exploring, catching, and battling. Food is a rare focus, and so when they do focus on it, it's usually because it's a special occasion. I.e., it's a special meal.